# Optimizing dplyr summarise model run

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, dtplyr

Looking to optimize summarise within dplyr when running a model over several obs. The end goal is to 1.) run a model for all relevant obs, and 2.) estimate the response value when the predictor variable ='s 0. There could be a solution where summarizing with the full model details/object doesn't need to be stored. I have converted the df to a data table to improve performance as well. See code below where df is a generic data frame. We are talking process here so reprex should not be required. Running a gam instead of scam takes a fraction of the time.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(dtplyr)
library(scam)

dt <- data.table(df)

ptm <- proc.time()
new_dat <- dt %>% 
   summarise(scam_model=list(scam(B ~ s(A, bs="mpi"))), .by = c(X,Y))
proc.time() - ptm
```

this portion is less likely to cause issue

```
pred_df <- data.frame(A = 0)
scam_predict <- function(m) predict(m,pred_df)
new_dat$scam_pred_0 <-sapply(new_dat$scam_model,scam_predict)
```

## Update:

I updated the code (see below) and received an error alluding to model issues and potential parameter estimation/optimization issues - Error in bfgs_gcv.ubre(gcv.ubre_grad, rho = rho, G = G, env = env, control = control) :
object 'old.alpha' not found

```
ptm <- proc.time()
new_dat <- dt %>% 
   fgroup_by(X,Y) %>%
   fsummarise(scam_model=list(scam(B ~ s(A, bs="mpi"))))
proc.time() - ptm
```

Comment: What sort of data should we assume is in this generic data frame? It will be much easier to benchmark potential answers if we can all work with the same example data.

Comment: In my testing just now, "converting the df to data.table` doesn't necessarily translate to data.table being used for subsequent steps. `data.table(x = sample(1:1E6, size = 1E7, TRUE), y = rnorm(1E7)) -> a_dt` then I get 10x better performance for `a_dt |> lazy_dt() |> summarize(y = mean(y), .by = x) |> collect()` vs. `a_dt |> summarize(y = mean(y), .by = x)`